# Determine identity on IdentityServer4 *SERVER*

Tags: identityserver4

Please read this carefully, as I'm pretty sure people will answer a different question to the one I'm asking.

I have an IdentityServer4 server, that allows users three methods of authentication (we have multiple sources of truth at the moment): custom (userid/pwd in SQL), ldap (user/pwd in AD) & integrated windows (no password required).  These work lovely, and when I'm in my client MVC application I can get at the identity and claims, regardless of which method I used to authenticate.

The question I have is how do I understand which user has logged on to the SERVER (not the client MVC!).  I can see the server is maintaining cookies, which must hold this info.  Bear in mind that `User.Identity.Name` will return the Windows Authentication information before they have 'logged in' to my software. i.e. `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` always returns `true`.  They may well go on to choose the SQL authentication method.

I'm guessing that is has something to do with `HttpContext.Authentication.GetAuthenticationInfoAsync` but I'm not clear on what `authenticationScheme` to pass in, as the last call to `SignInAsync` called an overload that didn't specify that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I understand what is going on here now.  The way I check to see if the user is authenticated on the server is to check for the `sub` claim.  That will only be present if they've been through the authentication process.

```
var sub = User.FindFirst(JwtClaimType.Subject)?.value;
```

If that's null then I know they're not authenticated.  If it's not null then I know I can read the `JtwClaimType.Name` and it NOT be their Windows Authenticated account name.